# hibernate mapping with alternate target column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a model objects relationship such as this:

```
@Table(name="cables")
class Cable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="dstport_id")
    private Port dstPort;
    @Column(name="srcport_id")
    private Port srcPort;
}
@Table(name="ports")
class Port {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Cable cable; // Here's the mapping that should point to cables.dstport_id or cables.srcport_id whatever is present
}
```

In this relationship the mapping is a One-to-One mapping through Cable's dstport_id OR srcport_id columns. A cable could be connected to none, one or two (exclusively different) ports. A Port could be connected to none or only one cable and to it's either endpoint. So, is there a way in Hibernate to map such a relationship inside the Port entity (there's no tricks to map it inside the Cable entity)?

Comment: Please post your schema as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to define the relationship from Port to Cable with only *one* association in Port.

In my view, your best option would be to define 2 optional, one-to-one associations to Cable in Port (`dstPortCable` and `srcPortCable`, say) using the 'mappedBy' joining method, and then define a method in Port, thus:

```
public Cable getCable() {
    if (dstPortCable != null) {
        return dstPortCable;
    }
    if (srcPortCable != null) {
        return srcPortCable;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's the only way I've implemented in the lack of (known to me) simplified notation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So as far as i have understand you need `One to Many mapping ( Cable to Port) in Cable.java` and `One to One mapping in Port.java` class.

So in Calble.java you can do as follows -

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "srcport_id",nullable=false)
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_srcport_id")     
private List<Port > ports= new ArrayList<Port >();
```

and in Port.java -

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "srcport_id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)  
private Calble Calble;
```

Comment: No, I need 2 different One-to-One mappings from Cable to Port (2 endpoints of a cable each connected or not to its port independently) and a single One-to-One mapping from Port to Cable but with variative target column to solve mapped entity object (a port could be connected to either SRC endpoint or DST endpoint of a cable).